# Yara one rule against multiple files

Tags: yara

I'm using Yara to detect multiple strings in multiple files for example:

File A : toto
File B : titi
Both file are in a directory repo

Yara rule (test.yar) :

```
rule test
{
strings:
$ = "toto"
$ = "titi"
condition:
all of them
}
```

And i run the commnand line :

```
yara test.yar -r repo/
```

But this rule will never match.
How can i do ?

PS : I can't merge the two file into one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The condition field is set to `all of them` which means that the files will match, only if they have the string toto AND the string titi.

Based on your question, you are looking for the condition `any of them`, which will match if titi OR toto is in the file.